# How to iterate all variables in var section of Golang

Tags: go

I have a file with `var` block. Is there way to get all variables in the block, including original variable name and value?
`reflect` can do such things but how can I get the variable names form other package?

```
package data

var(
    Str1 = "foo"
    Str2 = "bar"
    Int1 = 123
)
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make to much sense.  If you want get a variable from another package and that variable is exported (capitalized), then it's packagename.VariableName... eg.  data.Str1 is how you would access it.. There is no built in i'm aware of that lets you iterate over all the exported variables in a vars block... for that, write a custom file parser to grab the variables and determine type.  That being said, it's probably easier to just access the exported variables the "normal" way.. `demo.Str1`, `demo.Str2`, `demo.Int1`, etc..

Comment: Thanks for the advise. My purpose is to expose the variables and register them to my global error code system.
I will parse the source code and extract the variables, and that's may be the easier way.

Comment: If you own the package. Then another way would be creating a map[string]error, that has a copy of the vars. Where the key is variable name and the value is the contents of the variable. That would require double book keeping, adds memory usage, and slight redundancy.. But then you'd  also be able to access all the errors with a single exported value.